# Transparent <div> to prevent right-click, Save As

Tags: html, css, ajax

Conceptually, could once create a div, display the content and then put a transparent div over the content so if the user right clicks -> Save As, Save Image, etc and they won't get anything when they do it?

Comment: Well, that might stop one person. All the rest will either copy the file from their cache, use firebug or their other developer tools to delete your div, or any one of a million other things to save the image that you think is oh so worth protecting, but are still considering posting on your site.

Comment: It's possible, but I absolutely abhor and generally eschew sites that try to take these preventative measures (especially if they just block the context menu altogether) - at times it's *helpful* to be able to see how things are done. And if a person really cares about it, they'll still steal it.

Comment: @PeterLaCombJr: Don't forget about Tamper Data plugin and just look at (and re-execute) the query that fetched the image. ;-)

Comment: IMO the best thing to do if its a photo site is watermark the images until customers pay for them. Just like everyone said, if someone wants it they'll get it. The things discussed here will turn off the casual people from doing it though.

Comment: Firefox -> Tools -> Page Info -> Media = I got it :)

Answer (score 5):

yes but it's just as worthless as

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

if someone want to copy your content they will

Comment: useless but very cool this `oncontextmenu="return false;"` didn't know about it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

An empty div would still make the content below clickable. One technique sometimes used is to do a similar thing, but use a transparent gif or png which would cover the content, or to use javascript to disable the contextual menu.

In any case, if someone wants to save the content, there's not really anything you can do to stop them.

Answer (score 0):

Make a div which position is fixed then put transparent image.

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/huhu/ZePMg/1/