# Disable Image Save option by right click option

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [prevent saving image from my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018802/prevent-saving-image-from-my-site)
>   [Transparent <div> to prevent right-click, Save As](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514610/transparent-div-to-prevent-right-click-save-as)

Hi guys is there any way to disable image "save","copy","save as" option by right click user mouse.Because i don't want any one to save my images.There are some scripts are available but they are not valid for all browsers.Any help which should be valid for all type browsers.

Comment: Just don't do it. Users can save the images anyway and it's very annoying when you want a contextual menu and you can't have one (from a user's perspective).

Comment: If you disable right click for user he can also make a screenshot and get your images. There is no 100% safety for that.

Comment: This has been covered so many times before.. check [this StackOverflow search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=prevent+right+click+save+as) and see if there are some results that suit your needs.

Comment: <pointlessComment>Sir, please learn to internet</pointlessComment>

Answer (score 6):

It's pointless to try to do this. If the browser can display the image then the user can also download it. You may be best off putting a watermark on the images.

Comment: Afraid of what?  And I doubt he's your boy.

Comment: yeah, I don't understand the comment. I don't have any fear.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
oncontextmenu="return false;"
```

Will disable the context menu when right clicked on image.

But *wont* stop the user downloading the image by direclty typing the url or taking a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

You could always put a div over the image element, that way the right click will be invoked against the div instead of the image and therefore no "Save As".

```
<div class="image">
<div class="covering"></div>
<img src="..." />
</div>

<style>
.image
{
position:relative;
}

.covering
{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index:2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

theres no way for doing it..
but using an empty gif (transparent method) you can prevent newbies from saving the real images